# How to open a subtab for a primary tab in a service console when clicked on a custom button in case pagelayout

Tags: service-cloud-console

i have a custom button on a case layout page .... when clicked on button  I NEED TO open a subtab with a name for the subtab ......this is to be done by using the onclick javascript ... anyone could u please help its very urgent ...

```
function openNewSubtab() {
    if (sforce.console.isInConsole()) {
        sforce.console.getEnclosingPrimaryTabId(openSubtab);
    }
}

var opensubtab = function openSubtab(result) {
    var primaryTabId = result.id;
    alert(result.id);
    var URLValue = url;
    alert("Value of the URLValue......" + URLValue);
    sforce.console.openSubtab(result.id, URLValue, true, 'offers', null, openSuccess);
}

var openSuccess = function openSuccess(result) {
    if (result.success == true) {
        alert('subtab successfully opened');
    } else {
        alert('subtab cannot be opened');
    }
};


//to set tab title on load
var pageLoad = window.onload;
window.onLoad = function () {
    if (pageLoad) {
        pageLoad();
    }
    openSubtab();

}
```

I CHANGED BY CODE  , BUT I AM UNABLE TO GET THE TAB TITLE IT IS STILL GIVING AS EXTERNAL PAGE ONLY

Answer (score 2):

Here's a VF page I created that opens subtabs immediately.  Then I added the VF page to the Console as one of the side bars (so it can execute).  I hope the example helps!

---

```
<apex:page standardController="Account"  extensions="ConsoleCntrlr_AcctOpenSubtabs" showHeader="false" sidebar="false">
    <apex:includeScript value="/soap/ajax/27.0/connection.js"/>
    <apex:includeScript value="/support/console/27.0/integration.js"/>
    <script type="text/javascript">  
        function openNewSubtab() {
            sforce.connection.sessionId = '{!$Api.Session_ID}';
            if (sforce.console.isInConsole()) { 
                sforce.console.getEnclosingPrimaryTabId(openSubtabs);
            }
        }

        var openSubtabs = function openSubtabs(result) {
            sforce.console.openSubtab(result.id,'/'+'{!PrContact1.Id}',false,'PR Contact 1',null);
            sforce.console.openSubtab(result.id,'/'+'{!LastPR.id}',false,'Last Ran PR',null);
            sforce.console.openSubtab(result.id,'/'+'{!UpcomingPR.id}',false,'Upcoming PR',null);
        };  

        var previousOnload = window.onload;
            window.onload = function() {
            if(previousOnload) {
                previousOnload();
            }
            openNewSubtab();
        }
    </script>
</apex:page>
```

My Controller:

```
public with sharing class ConsoleCntrlr_AcctOpenSubtabs {

    public Contact PrContact1 {get;set;}
    public Payrolls__c LastPR {get;set;}
    public Payrolls__c UpcomingPR {get;set;}
    Account Acct;

    public ConsoleCntrlr_AcctOpenSubtabs(ApexPages.standardController con){
        this.Acct=(Account)con.getRecord();
        Account tempAcct = [SELECT id, Payroll_Contact_1__c, Payroll_Contact_2__c
                            FROM Account
                            WHERE id=:Acct.id];
        this.PrContact1 = [SELECT id,name FROM Contact WHERE id=:tempAcct.Payroll_Contact_1__c];

        this.LastPR = [SELECT id 
                       FROM Payrolls__c 
                       WHERE Account__c=:Acct.id
                       AND Processing_Complete__c=true
                       ORDER BY PR_date__c DESC
                       LIMIT 1];

        this.UpcomingPR = [SELECT id 
                           FROM Payrolls__c 
                           WHERE Account__c=:Acct.id
                           AND Processing_Complete__c=FALSE
                           ORDER BY PR_date__c ASC
                           LIMIT 1];
    }//END ConsoleCntrlr_AcctOpenSubtabs



    //%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%  TEST  %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    private static testMethod void testController(){
        List<Account> Accts = new list<Account>{new Account(Name='Test Acct')};
        INSERT Accts;

        list<Payrolls__c> Prs = new list<Payrolls__c>();
        Payrolls__c PR1 = new Payrolls__c(Name='PR1',Account__c=Accts[0].id,PR_Date__c=date.newInstance(2012,3,1),Processing_Complete__c=false);
        Prs.add(PR1);
        Payrolls__c PR2 = new Payrolls__c(Name='PR2',Account__c=Accts[0].id,PR_Date__c=date.newInstance(2012,4,1),Processing_Complete__c=false);
        Prs.add(PR2);
        Payrolls__c PR3 = new Payrolls__c(Name='PR3',Account__c=Accts[0].id,PR_Date__c=date.newInstance(2012,1,1),Processing_Complete__c=true);
        Prs.add(PR3);
        Payrolls__c PR4 = new Payrolls__c(Name='PR4',Account__c=Accts[0].id,PR_Date__c=date.newInstance(2012,2,1),Processing_Complete__c=true);
        Prs.add(PR4);
        INSERT Prs;

        test.startTest();

        test.setCurrentPageReference(page.ServCon_AcctOpenMultTabs);
        ConsoleCntrlr_AcctOpenSubtabs controller = new ConsoleCntrlr_AcctOpenSubtabs(new ApexPages.standardController(Accts[0]));
        system.assertEquals(controller.LastPR.id,PR4.id);
        system.assertEquals(controller.UpcomingPR.id,PR1.id);
        system.assert(!string.ISBLANK(string.valueof(controller.PrContact1.id)));

        test.stopTest();
    }//END testController

}//END Class
```

Comment: Can you please tell me why we need to obtain the session id before getting the primary tab id?

Comment: You need to set the sessionId to use the API

Comment: Ok thanks. I asked as I did not see this in the official examples for these methods.